# What does this SED command do and how can I modify it for my use case?

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I have been asked to fix someone else code so im unsure how the command actually works as ive never had to work with regex type code.

```bash
sed -r 's/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})\s([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})/\3\/\1\/\2 \4/g'
```

This code reads the below txt file and is 'meant' to display the number in bold below.

```
placeholder_name                    01/01/2022 12:00:00  01/01/2022 12:00:01  STATUS    12345/15     50
```

This is output to a new temp file but the issue is that only the first character in the number after the '/' is displayed, i.e. for the above example only 1 is displayed.

How would I modify the above command to take the full number after the '/'. Alternatively, if there is a nicer/better way to do this id be happy to hear it

Note: The number in bold has a range of 1-99

Comment: The sed command is not doing what you described. See [what it is doing](https://regex101.com/r/4MFCYx/1), swapping year and day.

Comment: Thanks for replying, the command had several sed commands in so it looks like I was checking the wrong one, using the link I have now found the correct one, using @HatLess answer looks to have solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's#.*/([[:digit:]]+).*#\1#' input_file
15
```